# Upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 while keeping Unity

Tags: 16.04, unity, upgrade, 18.04

I've tried this on a VM successfully, but I'm wondering if this is the correct way to do it:

```
sudo -s
apt purge ubuntu-desktop
do-release-upgrade -d #don't use -d after Ubuntu 18.04.1 is released in July 2018
apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop
```

Purging the `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage before upgrading should prevent GNOME from being installed during upgrade, and installing `ubuntu-unity-desktop` after the upgrade should ensure all dependencies are in place for 18.04.

Still, is this how it should be done?

Comment: I have tested 16.04 to 18.04 upgrade 4 times and never did I have to purge before or reinstall anything after to have the Unity desktop. The upgrade did provide 5 desktops though and I had to set Unity as the default on the first Sign In.

Comment: Interesting... That also happened to me, but Unity was already default. Maybe that's the difference.

Comment: I'll be cloning 16.04 and upgrading to 18.04 again this weekend to see how they have improved 18.04 since last weekend. Maybe they fixed the default Sign In